# .htaccess ReWrite wildcard folder paths from host

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My desired result is change a file path as a direct decedent from root, where there are N numbers of paths.

For example:
www.host.com/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/1.jpg, where A~G is not always given.

Result:
www.host.com/images/1.jpg

This is what I have so far:
www.host.com/a/images  --> www.host.com/images

Using: `RewriteRule ^a\/images/$ images/$1 [L]`

What I need is a wildcard in front of /images/

Like this:  `RewriteRule ^(.*)\/images/$ images/$1 [L]`

I have also tried: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/images/$ http://www.host.com/images [R=301,L]`

What is the proper way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^.+?(/images/.*)$ $1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: How can I add second variable to retain everything after images path?
Such that:
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(/images/).(.*)$ $1/$2 [L,NC]

Comment: Throws an Internal Server Error

Comment: Do you have more rules in your .htaccess? Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.+?(/images/.*)$ $1 [L,NC]

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: And this is the only .htaccess you have, no other .htaccess?

Comment: ok replace your complete .htaccess with the code above and test again in a different browser. I believe you're testing with URL: `http://www.host.com/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/1.jpg` ?

Comment: Sorry, one more request.  Can I get a second variable $2 to get 'xxxxxx'. I have some paths that look like www.host.com/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/xxxxxx/1.jpg

Comment: Yes you can get that, let me add that rule.

Comment: How should this `$2` be used in rewritten URL?

Comment: For http://www.host.com/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/xxxxxx/1.jpg will be http://www.host.com/images/xxxxxx/1.jpg  Not all links are like this, some are just http://www.host.com/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/1.jpg

Comment: But that will be taken care by existing rule itself since it redirects everything after `/images/` isn't it?

Comment: With the existing rule:
http://www.host.com/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/1.jpg - works
http://www.host.com/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/xxxxxx/1.jpg - errors

Comment: That's very strange since I use: `/images/.*` Is this Apache you're using? What error do you get?

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^.+?(/images/.+)$ $1 [L,NC]` ?

Comment: Works now, I had to restart Apache.  Think it was cache somehow.  Thanks again I have sent you a tweet. Will buy you coffee/beer on me :)

Comment: Please get in contact with me. Have a small project and will compensate. Have a great day :)